# Japanese Imperial Calendar support in Eclipse/SWT DateTime

Tags: java, eclipse, localization, swt

I am testing Japanese Imperial Calendar support provided by Eclipse/SWT DateTime control. I tried the following but got the calendar in English only.

```
Locale localeImperialJapanese = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
Locale.setDefault(localeImperialJapanese);
DateTime calendar = new DateTime(parent, SWT.CALENDAR);
//Code to show the calendar in a dialog.
```

Then tried changing format and locale in control Panel -> Region and Languages but I could see Japanese texts but not Japanese Imperial Calendar.

Something is missing? Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any better/easier way to test this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP"));
```

can't be set. It will work with the system locale only. Hence changed the System locale and made necessary changes to the settings. Now working!!!:)